# Can't get associations to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Users "admins" create Events. So each event has its own URL like "events/1". On the public site (i.e., no authentication required).  A member of the public can buy tickets to the event.  All the admin has to do is post the public URL, i.e., "event/1" and it renders a form for the ticket buyer to fill out

I can't get the ticket_buyers to be associated with their respective event (i.e., event/1). Here is the result of running Event.first.ticket_buyers at the command prompt which shows nothing in the array, even though I have populated the first event with ticket_buyer data using the app form (not the command api):

```
irb(main):001:0> Event.first.ticket_buyers
  Event Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events"  ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  TicketBuyer Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "ticket_buyers".* FROM "ticket_buyers" WHERE "ticket_buyers"."event_id" = ?  [["event_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

**Event model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
  has_many :ticket_buyers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**TicketBuyer Model**

```
class TicketBuyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

**Events Controller**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!, :except => :show

  def index 
    @events = current_admin.events
  end

  def show     
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @ticket_buyers = TicketBuyer.new
  end

  def new 
    @event = current_admin.events.build
    @event.admin = current_admin
  end

  def create
    @event = current_admin.events.build(event_params)

    if @event.save
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name_of_event, ticket_buyer_attributes:  [:full_name,  :number_of_tickets])
  end
end
```

**Ticket Buyers Controller**

```
class TicketBuyersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, :except => [:new, :create]

  def index
    @ticket_buyer = TicketBuyer.all
  end

  def show    
    @ticket_buyer = TicketBuyer.find(params[:id])
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end

  def new
    @ticket_buyer = TicketBuyer.new
  end

  def create  
    @ticket_buyer = TicketBuyer.new(ticket_buyer_params)
    if @ticket_buyer.save
      redirect_to localhost:3000
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

  private

  def set_ticket_buyer
    @ticket_buyer = Ticket_buyer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def ticket_buyer_params
    params.require(:ticket_buyer).permit(:full_name,  :number_of_tickets)
  end
end
```

**Database schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160705212350) do

  create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "full_name"
   end

  add_index "admins", ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "admins", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "name_of_event"
    t.integer  "admin_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
  end

  add_index "events", ["admin_id"], name: "index_events_on_admin_id"

  create_table "ticket_buyers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "full_name"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
  end

  add_index "ticket_buyers", ["event_id"], name: "index_ticket_buyers_on_event_id"
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
    resources :events do
      resources :ticket_buyers do
  end
end
```

**ticket_buyers/index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

  <table class='table table-striped table-hover'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number of tickets</th>
        <th colspan="4"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @ticket_buyer.each do |ticket_buyer| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to ticket_buyer.full_name %></td>
          <td><%= link_to ticket_buyer.number_of_tickets %></td>        
        </tr>
     <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </table>
<%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested in your UPDATE and I got the following error at localhost:3000/events/event_id/ticket_buyers:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TicketBuyer create action, you need to associate the record with the event after you create it:

```
class TicketBuyersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, :except => [:new, :create]

  def create  
    @ticket_buyer = TicketBuyer.new(ticket_buyer_params)

    if @ticket_buyer.save
      # This line below links it to your event
      Event.find(params[:event_id]).ticket_buyers << @ticket_buyer
      redirect_to localhost:3000
    else
      render('new')
    end  
  end
```

You could also create the ticket_buyer using the event itself as below:

```
def create  
  @ticket_buyer = Event.find(params[:event_id]).ticket_buyers.new(ticket_buyer_params)

  if @ticket_buyer.save
    redirect_to localhost:3000
  else
    render('new')
  end
```

This will automatically add the correct event_id to the model when building it. Also, do make sure you have ran a migration adding the event_id column to the ticket_buyers table.

UPDATE:

To show the correct ticket_buyers in the index action, you need to load the event instead, then use you can loop through the associated ticket_buyers for that that event:

TicketBuyersController:

```
def index
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
end
```

Index View:

```
<tbody>
  <% @event.ticket_buyers.each do |ticket_buyer| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to ticket_buyer.full_name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to ticket_buyer.number_of_tickets %></td>        
    </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you.  The results of my Event.first.ticket_buyer query in the console now shows the correct ticket buyer for the first event.  However, my views/ticket_buyers/index.html.erb still shows all ticket_buyers, even for other events.  I have tried various changes but nothing seams to work.  Can you please look over that template file posted above and let me know if you have any suggestions?  Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show only that events ticket_buyers. If that works please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I made the change to the index view you recommended in your update and I got the following error when I went to localhost3000/events/event_id/ticket_buyers:

Comment: Completed 404 Not Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event with 'id'=event_id):
  app/controllers/ticket_buyers_controller.rb:8:in `index'

Comment: Line 8 in ticket_buyers_controller.rb is the line you suggested: @event=Event.find(params[:event_id])

Comment: The URL is localhost3000/events/<EVENT_ID>/ticket_buyers. <EVENT_ID> being the numerical id of the event itself e.g 1 - localhost3000/events/1/ticket_buyers

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're not saving the event id against the ticket_buyer record. I wonder why you're also not validating the presence of ticket_buyers. 
An immediate quick fix is to add your event_id to your `ticket_buyer_params` like so:

```
def ticket_buyer_params  
  params.require(:ticket_buyer).permit(:full_name, :number_of_tickets, :event_id)
end
```

Comment: He has nested routes so the event_id is passed in the post route itself, it doesn't need to be passed in the form.